# pip is installing to Python 3.7, but I am only able to access Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I have Python 3.5.7 installed and some version of Python 3.7. Python 3.7 was definitely installed via homebrew, but I may have installed Python 3.5 manually. pip3 is installing packages to the folder for Python 3.7, and I want to use Python 3.7, but I don't know how. The command python3 uses Python 3.5 and there doesn't seem to be a file for Python 3.7.

```
usern$ which python3 
/usr/local/bin/python3
usern$ python3
Python 3.5.7 (default, Apr 18 2019, 12:58:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
exit()
usern$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.7
usern$ pip3 --version
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
usern$ /usr/local/lib/python3.7
-bash: /usr/local/lib/python3.7: is a directory
usern$ /usr/local/bin/python3.7
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.7: No such file or directory
usern$ python3.7
-bash: python3.7: command not found
```

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of python installed. Try `ls -l /usr/local/bin |grep python` to see if you have another python version in /usr/local/bin. Or just try `python3.7 --version`. The command `python3` might just be symlinked to version 3.5.

Comment: `head -1 $(which pip3)`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

I actually just used

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

and this worked perfectly well. My Python 3.5 folders were deleted, but everything works as desired with Python 3.7.

Answer (score -1):

1. you go to 'go' in finder and press Alt/option
2. then click on the library folder and open it
3. you will find a python folder in it
4. delete it and again install python latest version from the website
5. after this your version will change